# Override both types of constructors when extending object

Tags: javascript

Some objects in Javascript, such as Date, have two types of constructors.

> Date()
>
> ```
> When called as a function, returns a string representation of the current date and time, exactly as new Date().toString() does.
> ```
>
> new Date()
>
> ```
> When called as a constructor, returns a new Date object.
> ```
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#constructor

For some objects, like Date, that I need to extend I can use `class extend` to override the constructor to add additional functionality.  While that works great when used when the object is initialized with the `new` keyword, if you use try to use the function type constructor it fails with

> TypeError: Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'

So how can you extend an existing object so that both types of constructors remain viable?

Comment: I don't think you can do this using `class` syntax. You need to use the older prototype syntax. The constructor function can check whether `this` is set to an instance of the class.

Comment: "*When called as a function, returns a string*" - that is not a constructor.

Comment: "*For some objects, like Date, that I need to extend*" - you really should not extend `Date`. Why do you think you needed to?